# Rendering an animated heightmap

Tags: animation, displacement, height-map

I'm looking for a method of creating animated displacement maps for Keyshot, such as this one:

[Full animation here](https://media.keyshot.com/video/maps/KeyShot_DisplacementAnimation_Map_01.mp4)
[image]

This particular one was made in After Affects - which I do not use.

I'm wondering if it's possible to create physics simulations in Blender, which can then be rendered in a similar greyscale heightmap format. That way I can create some detailed 2D animations without AF.

Comment: You can create this sort of animation, yes, the one you show looks like voronoi, but what do you mean by "create physics simulation"?

Comment: @moonboots Yeah I asked in a rather odd way. What I meant to say, is that I want to generate physics simulations in Blender & then render them in a 2D format for use as a displacement map animation. I guess I didn't need to mention that part hah. Basically I just want to render an animation as a heightmap pass.. if possible


Edit: So far the closest suggestion I've found is to export an animation as individual frames, and then bulk process them into heightmaps via Photoshop

Comment: I guess it all depends on the final goal, maybe that's what you should show? Because what you ask seems a bit different than the animation you show, which could be done with a rather simple node setup I think...